# Sql request to Eloquent ORM laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a small problem for a personal project and I confess I don't really understand how to do it with eloquent from Laravel. I can make the sql query but I have a big problem converting it to eloquent.
Here is my problem: I would like to link two tables to an intermediate table.

Here is my intermediate table:
all columns :

```
dish_type_id |  recipe_id
```

Here is my recipe table:
all columns :

```
recipe_id|  label | image | etc...
```

Here is my dish_type table:
all columns :

```
dish_type_id |  dish_name
```

I would like display all the information of recipe and the dish with my intermediate table :
That's my sql request :

```
select * from recipes_dish_type as rcpDish join dish_type dish on dish.DISH_ID = rcpDish.DISH_ID join recipes rcp on rcp.RECIPE_ID = rcpDish.RECIPE_ID;
```

For the moment, I have a `Recipe` and `DishType` model.

Is there any solution with eloquent to have the same thing?
I check `belongsTo` but there is only one way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can eager load these relationships with [`with()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-multiple-relationships):

```php
$dishTypes = DishType::with(['recipe', 'dish'])->get();
```

Just double check 'recipe' and 'dish' are correct for your relationships.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, in fact I see that I do not understand well the relationship belongTo and hasMany and especially in what case to use it. Even with the documentation provided by Laravel it's quite hard to understand, would you have an example?